# String Manipulation within a JSON array using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am writing a bash script and I am looking to replace a character within a JSON field in a JSON array. In this case, I am trying to change the `"."` (period) character to a `"-"` (hyphen) in the `name` field. I am using jq to parse my JSON. Any tips on how I can achieve this will greatly help. Thank you!

Bash Script so far:

```
RAW=$(curl ${URL})

function manip() { 
    # Function for string manipulation.
}

echo "${RAW}" | jq '.data | .[].name = $manip' # Unable to make a function call in there.
```

Sample JSON:

```
[
    {"id":"1","name":"a.a"},
    {"id":"2","name":"b.b"},
    {"id":"3","name":"c.c"}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {"id":"1","name":"a-a"},
    {"id":"2","name":"b-b"},
    {"id":"3","name":"c-c"}
]
```

Comment: Why do you want to call a shell function to manipulate JSON inside jq? Why not use jq's own functions?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is [
    {"id":"1","name":"a-a"},
    {"id":"2","name":"b-b"},
    {"id":"3","name":"c-c"}
]

Comment: @Inian I am not familiar with the functions that jq provides. Do you mind directing me to any that would help with this?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace a dot with a dash, use the `sub` function:

```
jq '.[].name |= sub("\\."; "-")' file.json
```

Comment: Presumably `gsub` would be the appropriate function to use here, in general.